# jquery addition operation on each function

Tags: jquery

Here i'm having set of input fields with the input.selectedtable and with different different values.

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" value="1" class="selectedtable" />
<input type="hidden" value="2" class="selectedtable" />
<input type="hidden" value="3" class="selectedtable" />
<input type="hidden" value="4" class="selectedtable" />
<input type="hidden" value="5" class="selectedtable" />
<input type="hidden" value="6" class="selectedtable" />

<input type="text" value="" id="selected" />
```

Now i want to add (operation) all values which is having input.selectedtable

**JQUERY**

```
$('.selectedtable').each(function() {
    var total = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    $('#selected').val(parseInt($('#selected').val()), 10) + total; 
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/naresh_k28/398U4/)

How can i do this, can anyone help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var total = 0;
$('.selectedtable').each(function() {
    total += +$(this).val();
});
$('#selected').val(total);
```

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/398U4/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add all the values of input.selectedtable
then you can use this

```
var total=0;
$('.selectedtable').each(function() {
     total+= parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
});
$('#selected').val(total);
```

and if want to add all the values of input.selectedtable and present value of selected then you can use this

```
var total=0;
$('.selectedtable').each(function() {
     total+= parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
});
$('#selected').val((parseInt($('#selected').val()), 10)+total);
```